# Building an index with multiple tables in ElasticSearch/Logstash 7.0

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have 20 tables in Oracle, all of them contain (among others) the following columns: id, name, description and notes. I would like the user to enter a text, the text to be searched in either name, description and/or notes of all the tables, and the result to return which table(s) and id(s) has the text.

In the Logstash 7.0 configuration file, do I need to define one jdbc input for each table? Or should the input be a single select with an union of all the tables?

Comment: You can make an external script that runs logstash and it accepts a parameter equal to the name of your oracle tables. You can then add that parameter in the jdbc input query and send each table data to elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my answer for the above mentioned question is combine all tables info in single json.Then index it you can solve the problem in an easier way.

Comment: In the end I added to the input part one jdbc entry for each table